# Phonegap FileTransfer() error FileTransfer is not defined

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have already read most of the questions about this and nothing helped so far, that's why I'm asking here.

**I'm trying to dowload a .pdf when clicking on this:**

```
   <a onclick="BeginDownload()" class="link" href="#">My guides</a>
```

**This is the function (I use it between  tags in the header):**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
function init()
{
BeginDownload();
}

    function BeginDownload() {
    var fileDownloadPDF = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI("http://www.ltz.de/de-wAssets/docs/management-guides/en/ltz-management-guide-brown-lite-en2013.pdf");

    fileDownloadPDF.download(
                              uri,
                              pathToRoot + '/andrei.pdf',
                              function(entry) {
                              console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                              alert("File Downloaded. Click 'Read Editable Downloaded File' to see text");
                              },
                              function(error) {
                              console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                              console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                              console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                              }
                              );
}
```

**I have added the file and file transfer plugins, here's the proof:**
[image]
**And this is how my config.xml looks like:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>hi bi</name>
<description>
    sample stuff
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.3" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.5.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your "pathToRoot" being set? Your "BeginDownload" event is ever triggered?

Try something like this:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://www.ltz.de/de-wAssets/docs/management-guides/en/ltz-management-guide-brown-lite-en2013.pdf");
var downloadProgress = 0;
var filename = url.split("/");

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, function(oEntry){
    var pathToRoot = oEntry.toURL() + "/path/to/file/" + filename[filename.length - 1];

    fileTransfer.onprogress = function(result){
        downloadProgress =  result.loaded / result.total * 100;
        downloadProgress = Math.round(downloadProgress);
        console.log("progress: " + downloadProgress);
    };

    fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            pathToRoot,

            function (entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            },

            function (error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
    });

}, function(){ console.log("error");});
```